# how to write a unittest for a class?

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

```
class Hand:

def __init__(self,cards, total, soft_ace_count):
    self.cards = cards
    self.total = total
    self.soft_ace_count = soft_ace_count


def __str__(self):
    return(str(self.cards)+','+str(self.total)+','+str(self.soft_ace_count))


def add_card(self):
    self.cards.append(get_card())
    self.score()


def is_blackjack(self):
    return len(self.cards)==2 and self.total==21


def is_bust(self):
    return self.total > 21

def score(self):
    self.total=0
    self.soft_ace_count=0

    for x in self.cards:
        if x > 10:
            x=10
        self.total+=x

    #the following code will decide 1 =11 or 1 = 1
    if self.total <= 11 and 1 in self.cards:
        self.total+=10
        self.soft_ace_count+=1
```

I am trying to write the unittest for this 'Hand' class. Do I need a init setup for this particular unittest?
Here is part of code of my unittest. Thank you so much if anyone could help me with this. I just started in python. Any suggestions would help. Thank you. Neglect the indent

```
class hand(unittest.TestCase):

def __init__(self):
    self.cards=cards
    self.total = total
    self.soft_ace_count = soft_ace_count
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your class in a module named hand.py, you can place your unittest script in the same directory. It could look like this:

```
import unittest
from hand import Hand

class hand(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_init(self):
        cards = []
        h = Hand(cards, 0, 0)
        self.assertEqual(h.total, 0)
        self.assertEqual(h.soft_ace_count, 0)
        self.assertEqual(len(h.cards), 0)

    # def test_blackjack(self):
        #....


    # def test_score(self):
        #.... 


    # def test_OTHERTHINGS(self):
        #.....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

if you name your unittestscript for example unittesthand.py, you can run it via "python unittestscript.py". You will get the following result:

```
> .
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

The unittest component has executed all methods starting with "test" and executed. In the example the "test_init" method. This is NOT the initialization of the test, but the unittest for the initialization of class Hand.

Now change for example the code to "self.assertEqual(h.total, 1)", and you will see that the unittest component reports an error.

Now you can create additional cases for the other methods.You can also create a base test case with code that is always executed before and after the unittests and so on...